# onclick change plugin settings

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, conflict, jquery-jscrollpane

Here are the settings:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.info').jScrollPane(
        {showArrows: true, hijackInternalLinks: true, animateScroll: true}
    );
});
```

The problem is the `animateScroll: true` conflicting with the arrows but I need that for my internal anchor links.

I assume this will fix the conflict.
When you click the arrow button: `<a class="jspArrow jspArrowDown jspActive"</a>` it will change the jScrollPane settings to  `animateScroll: false` then when you unclick it reverts to `animateScroll: true`

I hope this makese sense. Any help would be great.

*Edit*

Sorry for not getting back sooner. I have set up a demo, as you can see the down arrow doesn't work. I think its related to animateScroll: true

http://jsfiddle.net/sVSsy/

Thanks

Comment: What is the question and what is the problem? Do you have any demo code up?

Comment: "arrows"?  "unclick"?  Give us something to work with here, where's your code?

Comment: Did you click and hold? Could you tell me your browser / os. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem seen on the official **scroll_to_animate.html** [DEMO page](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/scroll_to_animate.html) using both options you require when the DIV's width is around **600px**.

The solution is to use the **jScrollPane arrowButtonSpeed Option** with a value other than the default **0** when using smaller sized DIV's such as your **300px** width when using certain browsers, like Chrome.

This jsfiddle update also has a removed asset of a duplicated mouse script, replaced a duplicate ID 'one' with an additional ID 'four' for DIV content since an ID can only be used once. You'll see other speed settings with their default values that you can experiment with for any changes in your DIV size.

Here's the updated jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sVSsy/3/

Comment: Fantastic, I didn't see the arrowButtonSpeed option. Thank you so much for a great answer!

Comment: If you look at the non-minified **jquery.jscrollpane.js** file you will see at the very bottom all the options and default settings. That will give you excellent information about the API options currently used, to research a little further if required.

Comment: Great tip, I'll do that in the future as well.

Answer (score 0):

try to destroy and rebuild it with what attribute you want.

```
var api= $('#element').data('jsp');
api.destroy();
$('#element').jScrollPane({animateScroll: true});
```

Comment: could you show me how this would work with the example code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you try something like :

```
$('yourelement').click(function(){
    if($('panedelement').jScrollPane.animateScroll === true)
        $('panedelement').jScrollPane.animateScroll = false;
    else
        $('panedelement').jScrollPane.animateScroll = true
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can bind to the onmousedown and onmouseup events:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseup.asp

So, on mouse down on an arrow, you would set animateScroll to false, and on up you would set animateScroll to true.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how to apply that in this situation though.